# I need unbrick my samsung galaxy tab 10.1

Tags: rooting, boot-loop, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-10.1

I tied to root my samsung galaxy tab 10.1 wifi + IR PT-5133
I used this method https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8-gOZh7OxWM
After I completed the root prosses, my device was in a boot loop!
I tried rooting one more time, 
but the tablet continued in a boot loop but now IS IMPOSSIBLE start in a DOWNLOAD MODE
any suggestions

Comment: Steps to enter Recovery mode [here](http://blog.moes.as/2012/04/boot-samsung-galaxy-tab-101-in-recovery.html)

Comment: it may be possible that the tablet has not installed any recovery?
with the tablet in download mode, run the process to make ROOT from the PC installed with Odin. This process makes Root and installs RECOVERY???

Answer (score 0):

Connect your tablet to your computer and run

> adb devices

If your tablet is detected then execute

> adb reboot bootloader

Your tablet will then be in the download mode.

Comment: You need to use the "ADB mode", have the option enabled "Android debug" (enables debugging mode ADB) from development ????

Comment: @MauroEmilianoFerrara adb is enabled during boot and while in recovery.